# Are There Any Text Browsers for iOS?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications, ios, ipod, web-browsing

I want a text-only browser on my iPod. It is not jailbroken (nor do I wish to do so), and it is running iOS 4.2.1. Does anyone know of a way to install any text browser on iOS without jailbreaking? Any of these text browsers would be awesome;

Lynx, Edbrowse, w3m, Elinks, Links, Emacs/W3, Net-Tamer, WebbIE, etc

Comment: Have you tried to search these names one by one on iTunes app store? Particularly, if you do not want to jailbreak the iPad, there's no other source for apps.

Comment: I didn't find any of those apps by name in the app store, but I didn't know if there were any other text only browsers in the app store, or if there was a way to install one of those listed from something like iDos without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 2):

You could go on your iPod to a website like http://pizzaseo.com/tool-lynx.php to emulate the behavior.

Comment: That's kinda cool. Not quite going to do what I need, but definitely interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @Andris The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Atomic Web Browser and turn on Web Compression (uses Google mobilizer). This should leave you with a minimum of graphics on the page.

Comment: ...or Opera Mini and turn off image loading.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a text-only browser.

Comment: What's the difference between "browsing with no images or video" and "text-only browsing"?

Comment: I want a browser that isn't able to load images or video. I'm going for simplicity. Just text and hyperlinks, ignores everything else, including CSS.